# Splitting data separated by a | in a cell to new rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a Spreadsheet (see link at the bottom of the page) that has 1 row and 3 columns.
I want to take the data contained and split it out, resulting in a row by row breakdown.

Is anyone aware of how this could be done using a formula? It would save me a bunch of time doing it manually!

[DemoSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e7jIXw2vdup_JuneUImL8vM1YD8Ug1hJNFnpHBH147E/edit?usp=sharing) - This shows what the input and the desired outputs are

**EDIT:**

- The Input sheet shows the data as I have it, using metasyntactic variables as examples (real data will vary, but will always follow the same formatting).

For every email address in the email column, I need to do the following

- Get the list of managers and members and have it output as per the Desired Output 1 sheet. So for each entry in ColA, a row entry for each of the data in B and C, as if they were concatenated, split by " | " and transposed vertically.
- Repeat the above process but only for managers (as per the the Desired Output 2 sheet).

Comment: The sample spreadsheet gives "Access denied." See [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Ah, forgot to change the sharing settings! Try now

Comment: I don't think you have given enough info in the sample spreadsheet on how to get `Desired Output 2` from the data in `Input`. The `Email` values DemoGroup1@email.com, DemoGroup2@email.com, DemoGroup3@email.com all have the exact same `Manager` list, but they have a different `Manager` result in `Desired Output 2`. Why are the results different when the input is the same?

Comment: Manager lists may change, these are just metasyntactic variables to gap fill. I'll try to explain better. I'll update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

Output1:

```
=arrayformula({"Email","Members";
query(
array_constrain(
{
flatten(split(rept("|"&Input!A2:A,len(regexreplace(Input!B2:B&" | "&Input!C2:C,"[^\|]",))+1),"|")),
trim(flatten(split(Input!B2:B&"|"&Input!C2:C,"|")))
},
max(if(Input!B2:B<>"",len(regexreplace(Input!B2:B&" | "&Input!C2:C,"[^\|]",))+1,))*counta(Input!B2:B),2),
"where Col1 is not null",0)
})
```

[image]

Output2:

```
=arrayformula({"Email","Manager";
query(
array_constrain(
{
flatten(split(rept("|"&Input!A2:A,len(regexreplace(Input!B2:B,"[^\|]",))+1),"|")),
trim(flatten(split(Input!B2:B,"|")))
},
max(if(Input!B2:B<>"",len(regexreplace(Input!B2:B,"[^\|]",))+1,))*counta(Input!B2:B),2),
"where Col1 is not null",0)
})
```

[image]

You could optionally wrap `unique()` within the `arrayformula` if it is likely that you'll get duplicates in the dataset.